# More than one navigation item view iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchcontroller

Im trying to put a searchbar and a segmented control into a navigation bar. At the moment this is my code and it works but only one of them can be added.

`self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
 self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl1;`

Comment: use scopebar for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are replacing 1st view 2nd view.

try with the following code

```
CGRect titleViewFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

CGRect searchBarFrame = titleViewFrame;
searchBarFrame.size.width = titleViewFrame.size.width/2;//say, the search bar width = 0.5*search_bar_width

CGRect segmentFrame = titleViewFrame;
segmentFrame.origin.x = searchBarFrame.size.width;
segmentFrame.size.width = searchBarFrame.size.width;

UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:titleViewFrame];
searchController.searchBar.frame = searchBarFrame;//set here changed search bar frame
[titleView addSubview:searchController.searchBar];


UIView *segmentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:segmentFrame];
segmentView.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];

[titleView addSubview:segmentView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Comment: im unable to press anything outside the navigationbar size

Comment: you mean UISegmentedContol does not fire event?

Comment: no like i have everything setup; the search bar is on the navigation bar like it should be and the segmented control is under it like it should be, but when i press the segmented control it doesn't even notice that it is being tapped and it just taps what is under it. I think this is because it isn't on the navigation bar so i think i need to make the navigation bar a little longer. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: give me a screen shot

Comment: you should not change the default height of navigation bar. but if you do that it my have the change of rejection on the  apple review time

Comment: in that you case you can change the height of searchbar and segmented control both to adjust on navigation bar

Comment: i can select and interact with the search bar and ONLY THE TINY TOP BIT OF THE SEGMENTED CONTROL THAT IS ON THE NAVIGATION CONTROLLER.

Comment: i cant make them smaller or else they wont be interactable

Comment: and also how do i make them wider. notice how the segmented control doesnt go the whole way across

Comment: in you case yo should add segmented control in you tableHeaderView instead of adding on navigation bar

Comment: self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segmentedControl;

Comment: just add the line, all will solved. if not inform me

Comment: no i want the segmented controls to be visible no matter how far u scroll dowwn

Comment: then you have change the tableview height

Comment: start from just bellow the segmented control

Comment: what do u mean? the whole view is a tableviewcontroller

Comment: figured it out. Thanks for ur help nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

You need to hise your navigation bar!
And Customize navigation bar as a view!

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Customize a view for that navigation controller using UIView.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?